# Flutter application dependency on package that uses platform-specific APIs

Tags: flutter

I have two Flutter applications that leverage a shared library.  Let's call the apps A and B, and C is the shared library.  So, A and B both specify C as a dependency.

I initially created C as a ***package***, but now I am trying to refactor some logic that depends on Firebase out of A to C so that B can use it too.  However, now B fails to build:

```
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    /Users/anthony/project_b/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:6:9: fatal error: 'firebase_auth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.h' file not found
    #import <firebase_auth/FirebaseAuthPlugin.h>
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
```

If I run `pod install` for B, it says that there are **0 pods**:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
Pod installation complete! There are 0 dependencies from the Podfile and 0 total pods installed.

[!] The Podfile does not contain any dependencies.
```

A dependency like Firebase uses **pods**.  (I'm pretty sure this should not be 0.)

*Does C need to be a **plugin** instead?*

(Note that I am not writing any Kotlin or Swift code yet -- I just have dependencies that may do that.)

Answer (score 20):

I confirmed that a **plugin** library is not required; a **package** will be fine.

I traced my issue to the fact that I had run `pod install` manually.  I resolved it by deleting `ios/Podfile` and `ios/Podfile.lock` and then running `flutter run`.  You can see that this will run its own *Pod Install* step that makes things work.

I found the tip from here:  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/26890